# Python3.4 Pandas DataFrame from function

Tags: pandas, python-3.4

I wrote a function that outputs selected data from a parsing function.  I am trying to put this information into a DataFrame using **pandas.DataFrame** but I am having trouble.

The headers are listed below as well as the function.head() data output

## QUESTION

How will I be able to place the function output within the pandas DataFrame so the headers are linked to the output

## HEADERS

--TICK---------NI----------CAPEXP----------GW---------------OE---------------RE-------

## OUTPUT

['MMM', ['4,956,000'], ['(1,493,000)'], ['7,050,000'], ['13,109,000'], ['34,317,000']]

['ABT', ['2,284,000'], ['(1,077,000)'], ['10,067,000'], ['21,526,000'], ['22,874,000']]

['ABBV', ['1,774,000'], ['(612,000)'], ['5,862,000'], ['1,742,000'], ['535,000']]

Comment: Why the complicated data structure - a list of single string item lists? How are you reading in the data - it might be easier to read straight into a DataFrame?

Comment: I'm parsing  a website pulling in specific stats from different urls and the data is received in the structure when all said and done.  

What would you recommend?

Comment: Is it publicly available data - can you show me the websites you get it from? That would help me answer the question.

Comment: I'm pulling all the data from yahooFinance  from the income statement, balance sheet and cash flow pages....

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=AAPL+Balance+Sheet&annual

Comment: I'm currently parsing with regex and urllib libraries and decode the information into utf-8 which I think would be the reason for the strings... but I am a noob so I am not entirely sure

Answer (score 0):

-Loop through each item (I'm assuming data is a list with each element being one of the lists shown above)

-Take the first element as the ticker and convert the rest into numbers using translate to undo the string formatting

-Make a DataFrame per row and then concat all at the end, then transpose

-Set the columns by parsing the header string (I've called it headers)

```
dflist = list()
for x in data:
    h = x[0]
    rest = [float(z[0].translate(str.maketrans('(','-','),'))) for z in x[1:]]
    dflist.append(pd.DataFrame([h]+rest))
df = pd.concat(dflist, 1).T
df.columns = [x for x in headers.split('-') if len(x) > 0]
```

But this might be a bit slow - would be easier if you could get your input into a more consistent format.